# Azure Devops Defined iteration paths (sprints) is being ignored

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

under Project settings > Project configuration > Iterations > Default iteration.
I choose
`DevOpsTesting`

[Click here to see the setting I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQlWQ.png)
[After choosing the 'set' option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhmW6.png)

And set.
Note that DevOpsTesting is the name of the project and all sprints are under it.

But when I create a new work item the Iteration is set to DevOpsTesting\sprint 7..
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7197.png)
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to your descritpion, it should be workd after adding a work item in the boards page. You could go to the boards page create a new workitem and then  go to the work items page create the new work item under the specific iteration.

Each team should assign an iteration path to their work items that falls under the Backlog iteration path. Those work items will then show up on their product backlogs and boards.

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Have you tried create a new workitem in the boards page to check the status?